# why does bundler keep "changing" Gemfile.lock with no real change?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, bundler

I keep running into this every time I run some rake or bundler but there's nothing different about the old vs new and it's always this same gem, I've even committed those changes before and it still shows up

```
$ git diff
diff --git a/Gemfile.lock b/Gemfile.lock
index d2dc051..90b25d4 100644
--- a/Gemfile.lock
+++ b/Gemfile.lock
@@ -17,6 +17,13 @@ GIT
     nested_form (0.3.2)

 GIT
+  remote: git://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select.git
+  revision: 79755038ca61dafdfebf4c55346d4a2085f98479
+  specs:
+    country_select (2.1.0)
+      countries (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.3)
+
+GIT
   remote: git://github.com/rubenrails/rails-bootstrap-forms.git
   revision: 88b7ded3cdcca5af3070d6680f5e2b73303b277e
   branch: no_form_group
@@ -34,13 +41,6 @@ GIT
       rails (>= 3.1)
       railties (>= 3.1)

-GIT
-  remote: git://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select.git
-  revision: 79755038ca61dafdfebf4c55346d4a2085f98479
-  specs:
-    country_select (2.1.0)
-      countries (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.3)
-
 GEM
   remote: https://rubygems.org/
   specs:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect this is related to Bundler version. If you check the [changelog](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#172-2014-08-23), you can read:

> "Revert gem source sorting in lock files"

So, if different people with different Bundler versions are commiting to this repo, you probably should use the same version (for example 1.7.2).

You can check your Bundler version with:

```
bundler -v
```